# if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) is non-functional

Tags: c#, keycode

I have this

```
    private void toolStripTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
        {
            var items = new[] { 500+ objects here };
            if (toolStripTextBox1.Text.StartsWith("www."))
            {
                webBrowser1.Navigate(toolStripTextBox1.Text);
            }
            if (toolStripTextBox1.Text.StartsWith("http://"))
            {
                webBrowser1.Navigate(toolStripTextBox1.Text);
            }
            if (toolStripTextBox1.Text.StartsWith("https://"))
            {
                webBrowser1.Navigate(toolStripTextBox1.Text);
            }
            if (items.Any(item => toolStripTextBox1.Text.Contains(item)))
            {
                webBrowser1.Navigate(toolStripTextBox1.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=active&q=" + toolStripTextBox1);
            }
        }
    }
```

and it litteraly doesn't work. eg. I run it, no errors, all it does is play the windows error sound and won't be functional....

I know the code after the if statement is functional cause i have the exact same code on a button and it works just fine.

Comment: which technology? WPF? WinForms?

Comment: is there an exception being thrown?

Comment: @Pedro I am new to c# and I don't know what you mean, i guess .net framework?

Comment: you need to say what it is you are trying to achieve, what you are actually doing to the keyboard, etc.

Comment: @pm100 run some code if enter is pressed

Comment: try putting it in the `KeyPress` event instead of `KeyDown`..

Comment: Have you tried putting in a break-point and seeing what happens when your code runs? In my tests your code should at least run the `else` code. I suspect your event isn't even firing.

Comment: @Enigmativity I know the code after the if statement is functional cause i have the exact same code on a button and it works just fine.

Comment: Were you able to get it to work? I think that you need to make sure to bind the `toolStripTextBox1.KeyPress` event. See my answer below.

Comment: @JakeF. - Can you explain why your response relates to my comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your code in key up event, not key down, this will make event fully executed and eligible to read the key pressed.

I have adjusted your code and it works, you don't have to use `KeyChar` just use `KeyCode` instead and it should work.

```
private void toolStripTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.Return)
            //if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
            {
                var items = new[] { 500 + "objects here" };
                if (toolStripTextBox1.Text.StartsWith("www."))
                {
                    webBrowser1.Navigate(toolStripTextBox1.Text);
                }
                if (toolStripTextBox1.Text.StartsWith("http://"))
                {
                    webBrowser1.Navigate(toolStripTextBox1.Text);
                }
                if (toolStripTextBox1.Text.StartsWith("https://"))
                {
                    webBrowser1.Navigate(toolStripTextBox1.Text);
                }
                if (items.Any(item => toolStripTextBox1.Text.Contains(item)))
                {
                    webBrowser1.Navigate(toolStripTextBox1.Text);
                }
                else
                {
                    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=active&q=" + toolStripTextBox1);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the control has focus, or redirect the event to the control

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your `KeyPress` event handler:

```
private void toolStripTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
    {
        //Insert code here
```

It sounds like the problem may be that the method is not bound to the `KeyPress` event.

In the designer, click on the textbox, and then over to the side where it lists all of the properties, there should be a lightning bolt looking icon, click on that, and then scroll down to `KeyPress` and make sure it says `toolStripTextBox1_KeyPress`

**EDIT**

Alternatively, you can add the event handler programmatically. In your `Form_Load` event, add the code

```
toolStripTextBox1.KeyPress += toolStripTextBox1_KeyPress;
```

and in your `Form_Closed` event handler, add

```
toolStripTextBox1.KeyPress -= toolStripTextBox1_KeyPress;
```

Comment: error: Cannot implicity convert type System.Windows.Forms.Keys to 'char' edit: still does not work :(

Comment: make sure you include the `(char)`... that is *explicitly* casting `Keys.Enter` to a `char`.

Comment: Do you have that method linked to the `KeyPress` event on your `toolStripTextBox1`?

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint just on the first line of code inside your `if()` statement. That should work fine, there may be something else wrong inside of your code block. Add the rest of your code to the question and we can help you further.

Comment: Did you try to set a breakpoint? Maybe your `webBrowser1` object hasn't been instantiated yet or something. Also you could wrap it in a `try/catch` block and then show a `MessageBox` with the error details in the `catch` block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106519/discussion-between-dub-stylee-and-jake-f).